# Rejected Promise Resolves in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm not able to catch the rejected promise and I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Here's what I have

```
exports.signIn = (username, password) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(
     "select * from user where username=? order by id asc limit 1",
     [username],
     (err, result, fields) => {
     if (!err) {
      console.log("user result: ", result);
      if (result.length === 1) {
        let user = result[0];
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, res) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
          if (res) {
            console.log("user found: ",user.username);
            resolve(user);
          } else {
            console.log("Incorrect password");
            reject("Unauthorized Access");
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("user not found");
        reject("Invalid username");
      }
    }
  }
);
});
};
```

This is how I use the promise

```
app.post("/signin", (req, res, next) => {
 let body = req.body;
 let password = body.password;
 let username = body.username;
 db.signIn(username, password)
   .catch(err => {
     res.status(200).json({ err });
    })
   .then(result => {
     console.log("signin: ", result);
     res.status(200).json({ result });
   });
});
```

When I enter a correct password, it resolves properly but when I enter a wrong password it still resolves with the signin console message and an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` warning. I really don't see where I'm going wrong, perhaps an extra eye will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use promise as :

```
app.post("/signin", (req, res, next) => {
  let body = req.body;
  let password = body.password;
  let username = body.username;
  db.signIn(username, password)
    .then(result => {
      console.log("signin: ", result);
      res.status(200).json({ result });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(200).json({ err });
    });
});
```

Because, after catch if you will add any number of then handling, it will execute them all.

Comment: Can't believe it was just that! Thank you very much @developerKumar